# How to find yourself in huge php code? / advices for a first job newbie

Tags: php

I'm self-taught php programmer and I've just started working in my first company.
My problem is that I cant understand such a big code with so many files and it kinda puts me down.

How do you find yourself in such projects ? How do you manage to know that f.e. 'this function is for creating a select query', and 'this function is for sending the main submit form' etc ? What are your manner/advices that could help me go through that ?

Any other advices for a -first big company job- newbie ?
cheers

Comment: The development team should be using IDEs.

Comment: How does it make a difference if code is not maintained properly or crappy?

Comment: These skills are acquired along the time. On my company it can take up to 6 months for new developers to fully understand where everything is and how they work. Don't get put down, don't be afraid asking your fellow co-workers questions and you should be just fine. Good lick

Comment: I found using xdebug, netbeans & stepping through the code useful when I faced a similar situation - you can hit a URL & get netbeans to literally run a line of code at a time & show you what file is being opened, which lines of code are being run, set breakpoints, set watches on parameters etc.

Answer (score 6):

It's easy to get lost in a huge project, don't matter the language/tech used.

1) Ask a lot. Your coworkers are your first source of info. Just be sure to use them with parsimony. Don't pest the guys can help you with real problems (be sure real problems will happen sometimes).

2) Read the documentation. Documentation is often outdated but even a user manual can help when you need to perform basic user tasks to test a functionality.

3) Google, SO Code project, blogs... The internet is full of info about the basics and everybody needs to use it, don't be ashamed to use it.

4) Don't wander too much in uncharted waters. To maintain a huge system is like to sail in the sea. You can go far and deep and it's not rare to get lost when tracking a bug. In those kind of project you can take all day just to find the offendig line of code and change a coma. Don't be ashamed to add comments in code, if anyone asks you just tell it helped you to figure out the whole picture. Just keep focus on your mission.

5) Be sure What the system is about. If it's a logistc app you need to know the basics about logistc. If it's a shop site be sure to understand the step-by-step from creating a login to the "successfull payment" message. The system is a tool, it's helping companies and people to achieve some goal. Be sure how it's doing it.

Finally, keep cold. Don't try to get all in one day (or one week). Be sure you ill take your time do learn it. All projects have a learning curve. Just try to do your best and you ill be fine.

Answer (score 3):

I have almost an identical case of first job in a big company (just replace python with C# .NET). Here is my way of dealing with huge and overwhelming program.

1) Slow down, don't try to bite more than you can chew. Your company expects you to spend a good portion of your initial time here just to study the code and feel the program.

2) Actually study the code file by file. You don't need to go thoroughly through each line of code from the get-go, just get an understanding what the code from this file is supposed to do in an overall program structure.

3) Thoroughly inspect the executed state of your program. Get a feel of what the program does, HOW it does it, and what patterns are used (trust me, there WILL be patterns in codes/methods/naming) to achieve stated goals.

4) Around the time you start to understand the structure of the program, you will be most likely given an assignment. In most real-live cases, you will be dealing only with specific parts of code/files, relevant to your assignment. This is where you will need to become more thorough with your code research.

5) Don't hesitate to ask questions. Of course, if you keep bugging the person who gave you assignment with every little problem, which could be easily googles, you will only annoy them over-time and cause them to question your candidacy. Ask questions that cannot be found on the Internet (about the structure, etc.)

That should be a good starting point for you. After that, it is a matter of time when you start feeling comfortable with it.

Answer (score 2):

Well, good question. If you have big experience (5-13 years or more) in development you get some kind of feeling. With that feeling you can find a way to crack that code.

All developers use the similar logic. In big companies you need to ask about some documentation. If they don't have, that's their sloppy job and you need time to figure out "what writer wants to say".

The best way is to start from beginning. Go to index page, look what is there, follow includes and go to that files. If you see some function, search global where is defined and look in that file.

Also explore files, file & folder names because in name can be hidden answer of purpose of that file.

Working on big codes what is not like digging. You need to find your own way to learn and figure out how that work.

You need to ask a lot, bother your colleagues, read documentations and be persistent.

GOOD LUCK!